# stringTrim Knockout Utils not working when bundling

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, bundling-and-minification

When I bundle my knockout js files using ASP.NET MVC 4 and run my application in release mode (debug="false") the knockout utils functions are not working.

I'm trying to use:

```
if (ko.utils.stringTrim(searchTerms) == "")
       return;
```

But I get the error, Object has not method 'stringTrim'

My bundling looks like this:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scripts").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"
    ));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/ko").Include(
    "~/Scripts/knockout-2.3.0.js",
    "~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"
    ));
```

I'm pulling the bundles in like this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/scripts")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ko")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what do you get if you type ko in your chrome console? are you sure you have knockout?

Comment: Yeah since my viewmodel and bindings are working, forgot to put that down in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `ko.utils.stringTrim` is not currently identified as an exported method, so when Knockout is minified using Google's Closure Compiler the name of this method gets minified.

In the release build you end up using the minified file rather than the debug version.

The logic for stringTrim in Knockout is:

```
    stringTrim: function (string) {
        return string === null || string === undefined ? '' :
            string.trim ?
                string.trim() :
                string.toString().replace(/^[\s\xa0]+|[\s\xa0]+$/g, '');
    }
```

You could choose to add it to your project.

If you are only supporting newer browsers (IE9+), then you could just use string.trim(), otherwise you could potentially add it in older browsers as described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim